# Does Visual Studio Express C# 2008 come with the WPF libraries?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008

I need to know if Windows systems that have VS Express c# 2008 will have had the WPF libraries installed along with the VS installation (XP, so it's not preinstalled on the system).

Google didn't really turn up much.

Comment: there's an "express" runtime? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your after the development environment.
Then the answer is yes, although you won't be able to use extras such as Silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they will.

Express versions are limited not to have external plugins, which WPF certainly isn't.